# ¿Como puedo hacer que llegue una notificación diaria? andoid studio

Tags: java, android-studio, android-notifications

Estoy desarrollando una aplicación en Android Studio, el usuario registra información en un EditText, asigna hora y luego al oprimir un botón, esta información del EditText debe salir en una notificación cada 24 horas en el tiempo indicado ,quisiera saber como puedo hacer que llegue una notificación cada 24 horas.

```
 public void servicio() {
    Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MyAlarmReceiver.class);
    final PendingIntent pIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, MyAlarmReceiver.REQUEST_CODE, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
    long firstMillis = System.currentTimeMillis(); //first run of alarm is immediate // aranca la palicacion
    int intervalMillis = 1 * 3 * 1000; //3 segundos
    AlarmManager alarm = (AlarmManager) this.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
    alarm.setInexactRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, firstMillis, intervalMillis, pIntent);
}
```

Comment: Puedes mostrar el código que tienes hasta ahora

Comment: este es el codigo del servicio amigo

Comment: Quieres una cuenta atrás de cada 24 horas y al terminar el tiempo muestre una notificación ?

Comment: si Ashley G. pues la idea es que el usuario asigne una hora y se repita la notificacion todos los dias a esta hora